# Trying to print out items that are in a txt file, only prints curly brackets

Tags: python, python-3.12

I'm extremely new to coding; in fact, this is my first proper program. I'm trying to input items into a text file, save them, and then allow the 'user' to view the listed items if they do not wish to add a new item.

This is what I tried; sorry if it's a complete mess, but like I said, it's my first proper program.
It Does everything that i want it to do until you get to the part where you answer to view the books so far, but then no matter what you put in, it skips to have a nice day.

```
import ast

file_name = 'books.txt'

def save_book(input_book, filename):
    with open(filename, 'a')as f:
        f.write('\n')
        f.write(input_book)

def load_book(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r')as f:
        read = f.read()
    return read

try:
    books = ast.literal_eval(load_book(file_name))
    print('Library so far: ', books)
except:
    print('Creating a new file...')
    books = {}

while True:
    user_input = input('\n''Would you like to add a book to your library? Yes / No >> ')

    if user_input == 'Yes':
        books['New book'] = input('Please enter: [Author full name, Book Title] >> ')
        save_book(str(books), file_name)
        print(books['New book'] + ('\n''Book added to Library'))
    elif user_input == 'No':
        user_input = input('Would you like to view your books so far? Yes / No >> ')
        if user_input == 'Yes':
            print('Library so far: ', books)
        elif user_input == 'No':
            print('OK, Have a nice day :) ')
            break
        else:
            print('Unknown command...')

    else:
        print('Unknown command...')
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated, Thank you to anybody who answers.

Comment: Get rid of the bare `except` and see what error you are getting.  At least print the error with something like `except Exception as e: print(type(e), e)` so you can see what error is occurring.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is not a great way to read your input file.  Your input must be a valid Python literal, and it can only read one...not a bunch appended in a file.

Comment: [Edit] your question with a [mcve] (*please read the link*).  Describe inputs and expected vs. desired outputs and post complete tracebacks of errors.